# Creating New Excel Sheets in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to export a multidimensional array into an excel spread sheet. Where the 1st tab is the first matrix in the array, the second sheet is the second matrix, etc. etc.

My code:

```
    L=50
    for i=1:L
    xlswrite('C:\Users\Jessica\Desktop\Matlab\fishermatricies.xlsx',I_mat(:,:,i),i)   %Information matricies
    end
```

But for some reason the loop only inputs the data into the first 3 tabs, the remaining matrices, a new sheet is not created for them. How do I create new sheet for the additional matrices?

Thank you!

Comment: xlswrite automatically creates the sheets when the worksheet name is a positive integer (which it would be in your example). If you don't have Excel installed however, it will write to a text file in comma-separated value (CSV) format and it will ignore the sheet parameter. So the question is, do you have Excel installed? If so, what version? Also, what does it return as the output identifier as I assume it fails.

Comment: Quick note, you'd need to do [status,message] = xlswrite to capture the status and message. (I was referring to the message when I said output identifier.)

Comment: Thank you! got it

Comment: for some reason, it doesnt work with a for loop but a while loop it does. Weird?

Comment: That is strange! Not real sure why :S. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

tested your code with  Alec de Zegher's [xlwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38591-xlwrite--generate-xls-x--files-without-excel-on-mac-linux-win), it works just fine and does not need to have the Excel already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use following this code in Matlab

```
%Xlsx file name
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
%Colum Titles and Data
A = {'Time','Temperature'; 12,98; 13,99; 14,97};
%Number of Sheets in xlsx file
sheet = 1;
%Starting column
xlRange = 'A1';
%Xlsx File Writing Function
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```